# Scrolled Text in Tkinter (scrollbar issue) with .grid()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scrolledtext

I'm having some issues with a ScrolledText widget in tkinter.

The Scrollbar is not showing up.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

import os
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

#window variables
win = Tk()
win.title('TextS')

win_width = 600
win_height = 400

win.geometry('{}x{}'.format(win_width,win_height))

#widgets

title = Label(win, text="TextS", font=("Helvetica", 36, "bold"), bg="lightgray")
title.grid(row=0, column=0)

st = ScrolledText(win, width=400, height=300)
st.grid(column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

#main loop
while True:
    win.update()
```

Some Screen Shots:

With .grid() what I want to use:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5fdk.png)

With .pack() which I do not want to use:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgnTw.png)
(Has scroll bar)

Sorry if this is a noobie mistake,
Thank you!

Have a great day! :)

Comment: If you want the text area to be below the label, you need to call `.grid()` with the same column number for both widgets.

Comment: It looks like you're forcing the window to a specific size, and then putting in widgets that are too big to fit so the scrollbar becomes invisible. Have you tried either removing the call to `win.geometry`, making the geometry bigger, or making the default size of the scrolledtext smaller? There seems to be plenty of things to try.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you! I removed the win.geometry and that worked. But when I resize the window it changes how could I set it to auto resize?

Comment: it needs `win.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`, `win.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)` - and this row and column will use all new space when you resize window. And `  `st.grid(..., sticky='nsew')` to resize `ScrolledText` to this new size of row and column.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrolledText` uses `width` and `height` in chars, not in pixels - so you create very big widget and scroller doesn't fit in window. You have to use smaller values.

`grid` doesn't use free space when you resize (all of them use value `weight=0`. You have to use bigger `weight` to inform which row and column has to use this free space when you resize.

```
win.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)  # column 1
win.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)     # row 1
```

Now it will resize cells in row 1 and column 1 but it doesn't resize widgets in cells. Widgets needs `grid(..., sticky='nsew')` to resize in all directions.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is NOT preferred
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

# window variables  # PEP8: one space after `#`
win = tk.Tk()
win.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
win.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

title = tk.Label(win, text="TextS", font=("Helvetica", 36, "bold"), bg="lightgray")
title.grid(row=0, column=1)

st = ScrolledText(win, width=100, height=25)
st.grid(column=1, pady=10, padx=10, sticky='nsew')

# main loop
win.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

Using same code.

- set `geometry` to 350x300
- In line 20 set `ScrolledText` to `width=40`, `height=10`

  Set `column` to 0 not 1

You're set to go.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

#window variables
win = Tk()
win.title('TextS')

win_width = 600
win_height = 400

win.geometry('350x300')

#widgets
title = Label(win, text="TextS", font=("Helvetica", 36, "bold"), bg="lightgray")
title.grid(row=0, column=0)

st = ScrolledText(win, width=40, height=10)
st.grid(column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

#main loop
while True:
    win.update()

win.mainloop()
```

Screenshot output:

[image]